# FreeMarker - Remove comma from milliseconds

Tags: java, date, freemarker

Using FreeMarker, I want to display a date into milliseconds:

```
${mydate?long}
```

but I get as output a comma separated millisecond:

```
524,354,400,000
```

is there any built-in function in Freemarker to remove comma ?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It looks like as of version `2.3.17` you can use:

```
${myDate?long?c}
```

http://sourceforge.net/p/freemarker/feature-requests/72/

Comment: Works ! Yes I'm using 2.3.20. Thanks!

Comment: In my version (2.3.26), simply `${myDate?c}` will suffice, assuming that `myDate` is already a long/int.

Comment: This also works for me, thanks! If anyone else was wondering what the 'c' stands for: It means 'Computer language', so the comma's for human readability are removed: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_c

Comment: @lance.dolan thank you, worked for me, I added this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 24):

As an alternative you could write on your Freemarker template this directive:

```
<#setting number_format="computer">
```

This will remove all commas from numbers.

This works fine for Freemarker 2.3.23

More info about these directives can be found here:

http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Gil's answer, if you build the configuration inside your code, you can set the flag globally by :

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
...
cfg.setNumberFormat("computer");
```

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the comment of the accepted answer,

> In my version (2.3.26), simply ${myDate?c} will suffice, assuming that
> myDate is already a long/int.

This is worked for me

Thank you